# Can gtk menus displayed via gtk_menu_popup release focus?

Tags: c, linux, button, gtk, focus

I'm refactoring some code that normally requires the user to click a button for a popup menu to appear (it appears beside the button), what I'm trying to do is show the popup menu if the user hovers the mouse over the button icon for a preset duration and hide it again if the user moves onto another button icon.

However, activating the menu via `gtk_menu_popup` steals mouse and keyboard focus, I have made little progress trying to grab focus for the button widget.

Is it possible to return focus to the button icon?

Comment: Have you tried calling `gtk_widget_set_can_focus((GtkWidget *)menu, FALSE);` immediately after creating the menu with `GtkMenu menu = gtk_menu_new();`? You can let the menu grab the focus afterwards, if you call `gtk_widget_set_can_focus((GtkWidget *)menu, TRUE);` and after the menu is realized and visible call `gtk_widget_grab_focus((GtkWidget *)menu);`.

Comment: I believe that `gtk_grab_add` was the cause of my problems, invoking `gtk_grab_remove` did the trick, along with similar calls to the `gdk` subsystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging this turned out to be quite troublesome, as `gtk_menu_popup` grabs the gdk keyboard and pointer focus, which prevents one from stepping through the code with gdb, I eventually managed it by running the code in a VM and using a remote debugging session with gdb over SSH.

There are a few different mechanisms through which the popup may steal focus from the original widget

1. Via transient window relationships (only if you pass `parent_menu_shell`)
2. Via `gdk_pointer_grab`
3. Via `gtk_grab_add`

As I set the `parent_menu_shell` shell parameter to NULL, this meant that I had to undo the last two 'grabs', like so:

```
gdk_pointer_ungrab(GDK_CURRENT_TIME);
gdk_keyboard_ungrab(GDK_CURRENT_TIME);
gtk_grab_remove(menu);
```

This did the trick but focus gets temporarily stolen by the popup, which causes problems too